# Python Login API returns "Email or Password are wrong"

Tags: python, json

I am a Python newbie, using Python over win 7 professional.
Recently I started trying to write a script that will test all of our API's and the first one I started with is  the "Login" API.
Following is the code I wrote:

```
def main():

init()

print (colored("This script activates all Dashboard API's.\n",'yellow'))

accountId = raw_input("Enter the account name:")
print ("\n")
accountPass = raw_input("Enter the account password:")
print ("\n")
print accountId

get_token (accountId,accountPass)
```

def get_token(accountId,accountPass):
    header={"Content-Type" : "application/json"}
    url = '';
    url += '';

```
param = {"user" : accountId, "pass" : accountPass, "jsonrpc" : 2.0, "method" : "login", "id" : "test"};

print url+str(param)+str(header)
tokenId = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(param),headers=header)

print tokenId.text
```

The result I am getting is as follows:

```
http://<Server URL>{'id': 'test', 'method': 'login', 'jsonrpc': 2.0, 'user': 'XXX', 'pass': 'XXX'}{
'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
{"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"Email or Password were wrong!","data":{}},"id":"test","jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

I am using the correct user name and passwords.
The API code is written in PHP in case it helps...

Can you please help?

Comment: What version of requests are you using? You don't need to use `json.dumps`, just pass the param directly.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can try - strip the username and password, and pass the dictionary directly without encoding it as `json`:

```
def get_token(account_id, account_pass):

    param = {"jsonrpc": 2.0, "method": "login", "id": "test"}
    param["user"] = account_id.strip()
    param["pass"] = account_pass.strip()

    result = requests.post('example.com', json=param)
    result.raise_for_status()
    print(result.text)
```